# Azure media Player integration in iOS

Tags: ios, azure, widevine

I have gone through this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-develop-video-players) provided to `develop video player applications`.

But I didn't get any proper way of player implementation in iOS.

In this [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/cross-post-announcing-windows-azure-media-player-framework-preview-for-ios/) they have given a link to the github page, but github is showing an error message of `Page not found`.

Is there any proper document for `iOS Azure player` integration ?

Answer (score 0):

As you provided the documents & blog link and you did not find the proper implementation.

So please find the for demo implementation of azure media player at below location.

https://github.com/CloudMetal/azure-media-player-framework

It will help you to implement azure media player in your application.

Let us know if you have any comment on the same.